# Cheaper way to move objects to DEEP_ARCHIVE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

1) I was charged $0.05/1000 requests to move my objects to glacier with PUT requests with Ruby SDK v3. Is there a cheaper way to do this? I eventually need to move something like 10 million objects, and I was charged $50 after the first million.

2) Are AWS policy lifecycle rules free to transition objects between storage classes? We wanted to keep track of which objects are on DEEP_ARCHIVE from our app, but if it's going to cost $500 in order to do that.

3) One would think from the billing table that you would be charged for a PUT requests against an S3 standard object, where it says that lifecycle transitions are free, or at least be charged for PUT requests against S3 standard at a rate that is ten times cheaper than put requests against S3 Glacier. How can I move my objects to Glacier or Deep Archive without getting this massive bill? Is there some request that can change storage classes within the Ruby SDK which is not the prohibitively expensive PUT to Glacier?

Also - does this seem like an appropriate way to change the storage class of an object?

```
        obj.put({
          acl: "public-read",
          body: obj.get.body.read,
          content_length: obj.content_length,
          content_type: obj.content_type,
          storage_class: storage_class, # (GLACIER or DEEP_ARCHIVE)
        })
```

Comment: Voted to close for a lot of reasons. First, there are multiple distinct questions here. Posts should be about one narrow topic. Second, questions related to professional network or server administration belong on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0):

From [Transitioning Objects Using Amazon S3 Lifecycle - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/lifecycle-transition-general-considerations.html):

> **S3 Glacier and S3 Glacier Deep Archive transition request charges—** Each object that you transition to the S3 Glacier or S3 Glacier Deep Archive storage class constitutes one transition request. There is a cost for each such request. If you plan to transition a large number of objects, consider the request costs. If you are archiving small objects, consider aggregating many small objects into a smaller number of large objects to reduce transition request costs.

The [Amazon S3 pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) says: `Lifecycle Transition requests (per 1,000 requests) ... Glaicer Deep Archive ... $0.05`